# Nextjs - Accessing service-worker file on prod build throws 404

Tags: next.js, service-worker, clevertap

I have clevertap integration and they need to have the service-worker.js at the root level in nextjs project. Thus I kept the file in <kbd>public</kbd> folder. It works locally, but on production build, its returning 404.
Accessing as -  <kbd>await navigator?.serviceWorker?.register('/clevertap_sw.js');</kbd>

I tried changing to  <kbd>await navigator?.serviceWorker?.register('/public/clevertap_sw.js');</kbd>, but doesn't seem to work